# A set-up which is intended to make fun of someone

Tags: word-request

Please suggest a verb that depicts the following situations.

For example your friend calls you and says he had an accident but when you run to his house you find out that he has lied and it was a set-up.

What do we call my friend's act?

Comment: +1 but *a set-up* is different thing than *act*. *Prank* is the term for that *act* and not setup. However, that *setup* is done to play prank! :)

Comment: Just FYI *Setup* or *set-up* are equivalent (nouns), *set up* is a verb.
So your title is fine, the question should read *setup* or *set-up*.

Comment: Thank you Maulik and Jolenealaska for tips and all other answerers.

Comment: The common idiom for "prank" is "to play a prank (on someone)". Your friend played a prank on you. :-)

Comment: You ask for a *verb* but then you say "What do we call my friend's *act*?" Which do you want - a word for the act (a noun) or a verb to describe performing the act?

Comment: @starsplusplus I thought its obvious :) I wanted a verb for this act. I think prank is good but I was thinking of a verb Like that famous TV show called **"Punk'd"** For example : *"I have been Punk'd"*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Sure he did :) I have one for him too.

Comment: "Set up" already conveys this sense, also. If you say "I've been set up!" people will understand you, especially if you mean you've been tricked into something or framed.

Comment: And again with a verb, it depends on the intention behind it: he *tricked* me, he *fooled* me, he *deceived* me, he *played* me, he *put one over on* me, he *snookered* me, he *duped* me, he *fooled* me, *hoodwinked* me, he *got* me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Homayoon has alluded to, the word can vary with the reason behind the act.

A [*prank*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prank?show=0&t=1396844970) or [*practical joke*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practical%20joke) is for amusement

A [*ruse*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ruse) is to disguise an ulterior motive.

Answer (score 3):

If it's for amusement purposes, it's a "prank" which is usually used as a noun but *is* occasionally used as a verb.

I've seen it used here and there, but a few online dictionaries I've checked do not mention prank as a verb meaning to perform a prank (a practical joke), except for [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prank#Verb) which is less trustworthy but does provide an example from a [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/05/13/sports/football/13jets.html?_r=0):

> "If someone's **pranking** me," Rowlands remembered thinking, "they're going to great lengths to make it work."

Comment: Can you possibly expand your answer a little to make it more of a useful resource for future readers? Like maybe adding a source text and some examples? There's a good page in the help centre called [How do I write a good answer?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that might be of help too.

Answer (score 3):

You could also say:

> Your friend *deceived* you.

if there was a non-humorous motive.

Or you could say:

> Your friend was *pulling your leg*.

if it was for fun.

Answer (score 2):

There is *shenanigan*, which [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shenanigan) defines as:

> "A deceitful confidence trick, or mischief causing discomfort or annoyance"
>   "Mischievous play, especially by children"

Comment: I disagree. It's an act that's more negative as compared to 'prank'. Prank is the right word.

Comment: @MaulikV - If someone told me that he had been in an accident, and did so so convincingly that I rushed to his house – only to find him smiling, I'd put that under the umbrella of _shenanigans_ (which is often pluralized). Though I do like _prank_, I don't think there is a single "right word" to answer this question.